# $I_n=\int_0^1x^ne^xdx$. Show that $1 \le (n+1)I_n \le e$ for any $n \in \mathbb N^*$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

$I_n=\int_0^1x^ne^xdx$. Show that $1 \le (n+1)I_n \le e$ for any $n \in \mathbb N^*$.

I know $I_{n+1}=e-(n+1)I_{n}$ and also that $I_n$ is decreasing and $I_1 = 1$. I tried rewriting the inequality in a lot of different ways and I still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ 1 \leq e^{x} \leq e$. Just multiply by $x^{n}$ an intgrate to get $$\dfrac 1 {n+1} \leq \int_0^{1} x^{n} e^{x} d x\leq \dfrac e {n+1}$$.

Comment: I don't understand. I tried a similar approach but just started from the inequality $0 \le x \le 1$ and I ended up with $ 0 \le \ x^ne^x \le e^x$ and after integrating from $0$ to $1$ I got $0 \le I_n \le e-1$. I don't think what I've done is wrong but how would I know to start from $e^x$ instead?

Comment: @RaduGabriel For the upper bound use the fact that $x^{n}e^{x} \leq x^{n} e^{1}$ instead of $x^{n}e^{x} \leq e^{x}$. For the lower bound use the fact that $$x^{n}e^{x} \geq x^{n}$.

Comment: I understand now. I think the key was to see that $\int_0^1{x^n} = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: +1 really nice answer Kavi